# Flowable not returning value from Room DB

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I have problems reading value from RoomDB.

Here is my RoomDBInterface -

```
@Dao
interface RoomDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM accountTable")
    fun getAccountData(): Flowable<AccountModel>
}
```

The Repo that reads from this interface looks like this -

```
override fun retrieveAccountData() {
        Log.e("hi", "inside retrieveAccountData()")
        disposable.add(
            roomDao.getAccountData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ userData ->
                    Log.e("hi", "callback to upper layers")
                    callback?.onAccountDataRetrieved(userData)
                },
                    { throwable -> callback?.onAccountDataRetrieved(null) })
        )
    }
```

I just get the first log which is inside `retrieveAccountData()` but the disposable subscribe does not return the callback. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not to use Kotlin coroutines instead? May be your callback is null?

Comment: Could you give me an example please with room and coroutines? I am not sure how I could return some deferred when I insert, update to room. With Rx, I could just use Flowable or Completable. And between, I dont get the log "Callback to upper layers". So I am pretty sure it is not reaching the subscribe

Comment: Sorry for repeating question, but please double check (debug) the callback field first.

Comment: Checked... It is not null

Comment: I used single and it works now... With Flowable it is not working

Comment: Just guessing, you are using two parameters for `subscribe` method, please put the third one, override `onNext`, `onCompleted` as well.